# 410 (Gone) error on GET request nodejs reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Right now, I'm getting weird message in the console saying when I submit the signup form in my react component.

`GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/checkValidUser/sam123@gmail.com 410 (Gone)`

[image]

Here I am checking if the user with the entered email exists in the database or not.

---

```js
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { username, email, password } = this.state

    console.log("inside check valid email", email)
    const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/checkValidUser/${email}`)
    console.log(res.data)
}
```

`router.get("/checkValidUser/:email", usersController.checkValidUser)`

```js
checkValidUser: async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("inside check valid user controller")
    const { email } = req.params
    console.log(email)
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ email })
      if (user) {
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "User already exists" })
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "No user found with this email. You can register now" })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return next(error)
    }
  }
```

In Postman, the route is working fine. Currently, I have dropped the database and there are no users. So, it should return me the message of `"No user found with this email. You can register now"` but getting 410. Please help.

**app.js**

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require("mongoose")


const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const userRouter = require('./routes/users');

const app = express();


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  const webpack = require("webpack");
  const webpackConfig = require("./webpack.config");
  const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

  app.use(
    require("webpack-dev-middleware")(compiler, {
      noInfo: true,
      publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath
    })
  );

  app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler));
}

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/myApp", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Not connected to the database")
  } else {
    console.log("Connected to the database")
  } 
})


app.use("/api/v1/users", userRouter)
app.use("/*", indexRouter)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


module.exports = app;
```

**bin/www**

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('myApp:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [showing error if user email already exists in the database nodejs react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61454711/showing-error-if-user-email-already-exists-in-the-database-nodejs-react)

Comment: No, I didn't get answer on my previous question. So, I asked again.

Comment: Deleted previous post.

Comment: Ok, now can you add your main node file (server, index or app.js) and the error handler?

Comment: Added `app.js`.

Comment: Where do you use app after exporting? Add that file too.

Comment: Where's your `User` variable defined?

Comment: @TamasSzoke In the User model. https://hastebin.com/iyudurahek.js

Comment: @SuleymanSah I don't see if I'm using the app after exporting. Where do I suppose to use it?

Comment: You need to use app.listen somewhere

Comment: @SuleymanSah, Yeah, it's in `bin` folder. I added that file to my question.

Comment: Why don't you create the server easily with express? Can you replace `module.exports = app;`  with this `app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Listening on port 3000"));` and re try?

Comment: @SuleymanSah I added `app.listen(3001)`, and 410 error is gone now. So the problem was with port?

Comment: Ok I guess that server creation couldn’t handle email address in the url.

Comment: So should i change port number in the `www` folder? I chaged it to 3001 in `www` file, but now app is not running. Getting compiled though.

Comment: Just don't use the file in www folder, and use what ever port number in app listen.